# Where to start learning for writing driver for devices and capacitive screen?

Tags: device-driver

I am expecting some work in near future related to capacitive screen devices, there we have to write the software for capacitive touch screen. Please guide me how to start for that , and also how to learn writing driver software for a hardware in general like a modem , usb etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read a bunch of chapters from [Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) some time ago. It's a good book licensed under Creative Common license that explains how to write different kinds of device drivers. I only used it to know about concurrency in the kernel, block and network drivers but you could find it interesting.

Comment: thnaks for the answer , please see if u can find something related to Capacitive screens

Comment: You asked for some infos about device drivers in general, so I gave you this answer but I don't know anything about capacitive screens, I'm sorry.